# gitflow-maven-plugin: Remote branch 'origin/master' is ahead of the local branch 'master'

Tags: maven, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I use maven to create releases using gitflow-maven-plugin. My projects builds fine, unless I create a release calling the following maven command

```
mvn -B gitflow:release
```

This fails with the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.amashchenko.maven.plugin:gitflow-maven-plugin:1.9.0:release (default-cli) on project test: 
release: Remote branch 'origin/master' is ahead of the local branch 'master'. 
Execute git pull. -> [Help 1]
```

There are no changes on the master so there should be no such error, especially also cause the plugin does a fetch beforehand as shown in the log

```
16:03:21 [INFO] Fetching remote branch 'origin master'.
16:03:21 [INFO] Comparing local branch 'master' with remote 'origin/master'
```

Any clue what could cause that?

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I ran into the same problem. After the first release I have to manually reset/push-force the master branch in order to work for the next release.

Comment: Not at the moment, did not pursue the issue for now as we decided not to use gitflow for now

Comment: I found a workaround specific to building with Jenkins. I activated the option to delete the workspace at the end of the build. From that point on, it will actually correctly fetch master each time since all the local git files are wiped out each time.

Answer (score 0):

When I downloaded the workspace zip archive to inspect the cause of this problem, git showed that that master branch was indeed behind the remote master.

In the Jenkinsfile I only did

```
git checkout develop && git pull --rebase
```

I fixed the problem by pulling the master branch, too

```
git checkout master && git pull --rebase
git checkout develop && git pull --rebase
```

Probably a git fetch also would have sufficed